# SQL: error with inner join in an update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join

I can't found the problem in my request.. Here is my request and the 2 table:

```
UPDATE RESERVATION inner join client on reservation.numcl = client.numcl
SET reservation.numcl2 = client.numcl2;
```

Error:

```
   => [42000][971] ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
```

1. Table client
   [Client table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDE07.png)
2. Reservation client
   [reservation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0MZ1.png)

The solution:

```
UPDATE RESERVATION SET reservation.numcl2 = (select client.NUMCL2
                                             from CLIENT
                                             where client.NUMCL= RESERVATION.numcl);
```

Comment: Have you highlighted the first line only or missed a `;` after the first line?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by highlighted the first line but the inner join works perfeclty in a Select for instance. And the ; should be at then end right?

Comment: I think that it is not allowing you to `UPDATE` a join. It's looking for the `SET` keyword right after the table name, where it normally goes when one does a simple `UPDATE`...

Comment: @PatJones Yes, I thought that as well but i don't know the syntax for the inner join in update in oracle (I think that structure works in MYsql)

Comment: I have an idea. I work mostly with SQL Server, but I think the syntax will work for you. I'll post it as an answer shortly...

Comment: @PatJones is all right i juste found it, I edit the post with the solution!

Comment: @Rotciv the highlighting or `;` was because a lot of IDE's will only run the highlighted syntax if you had highlighted the partial query before the`SET` keyword. Ending the query with `;` before the `SET` would have been the same. Your solution seems to be updating every single row of the `Reservation` table. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @Hans Yes that was whay I want to do, in deed the goal was to have the numcl2 according to the numcl in client (the numcl2 came from a substituion of the first letter of the name/first char of the codePostCL and the old numcl)! Thx for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not support `join` in `update` (at least explicitly).  The equivalent for what you want to do is:

```
UPDATE RESERVATION r
    SET numcl2 = (select client.NUMCL2
                  from CLIENT c
                  where c.NUMCL = r.numcl
                 )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM client c WHERE c.NUMCL = r.numcl);
```

The `exists` is important, if you want to handle the cases where there is no match.

Comment: Ok i get the difference! But in my case they can't have a numcl in reservation that is not in client so I don't need to put it in right?  And what's the use of the '1' after the select in the exists?

Comment: @Rotciv . . . If you don't need to check for a match, then you don't need to.  I'm just pointing out what the equivalent syntax is in Oracle.  What follows the `select` is unimportant; "1" is easy to type.